# Suddenly All white render in Cycles

Tags: rendering

When I tried to render just a red cube, all I could see was just white.

How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is in your composition, I am not entirely sure what you wanted to achieve by this:
[image]

But you are basically not using your render at all...

It should be like this if you want to use white background with transparent render:
[image]

I am not sure where did you get the idea to use Movie Clip node and Render layers separately. Render Layers is your cube render...

Comment: oh, my mistake, Thanks :)